# esp-32 send image to Gdrive

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, iot

I am working for the first time with esp32 cam and I want to click images and store them in my google drive. However, when I run this code I always get the error
1)TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined
2)Script function not found: doGet (after deploying )
to deploy I did the following steps :
a)web app
b)execute as me
c)access to everyone

code

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var nombreArchivo = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")+".jpg";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, nombreArchivo );
  
  
   // Save the photo to Google Drive
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("ESP32-CAM");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("ESP32-CAM");
  }
  var file = folder.createFile(blob); 
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Completo')
}
```

Comment: doPost(e) is an endpoint for a webapp.  You can run it as a function if you supply the event object. [doPost request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters).  If you don't supply the event object then you get the error because it doesn't supply it's own parameters.

Comment: hey thank you for the help, however, I am unable to understand what exactly I must do...Can you please guide me in a little brief manner, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the rundoPost() function.  It runs the doPost(e) function and supplies it an object which get's stuck into e.

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.parameter.one == 1) {
    Logger.log('Go Click the Message Box to complete the function')
    Browser.msgBox('Hello World');
  }
}

function rundoPost() {
  let eObj={parameter:{one:1,two:2,three:3}};
  doPost(eObj);
}
```

You'll want to make sure that your supplied object is exactly like the one the trigger will supply so that you code will work as a real web app endpoint.

Comment: I tried using the method you suggested however i am facing the same set of errors

Comment: Put this on the first line of your function `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` and tell me what you get from the logger